# How to create fa bars animated menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to animate my i class fa bars so that the hamburger menu rotates and crosses on click.

I haven't been able to find a way to animate it, so found this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device- 
width, 
initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #333;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: 
rotate(-45deg) 
translate(-9px, 
6px);
transform: rotate(-45deg) 
translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: 
rotate(45deg) 
translate(-8px, -8px);
transform: rotate(45deg) 
translate(-8px, -8px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container" 
onclick="myFunction(this)">
<div class="bar1"></div>
<div class="bar2"></div>
<div class="bar3"></div>
</div> <script>function 
myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle
("change");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm having is how to implement it on my WordPress site. Could i put it on homepage and hide `fa-bars`, or is there a way of putting it in my head somehow and replacing original `i class` where the icon currently is? Basically how do i link it to my menu?

Tried this, didn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<i class="fa bars" onclick="myFunction(this)">
<div class="fa bars"></div>
</div> <script>function myFunction(x) {
x.classList.toggle("change");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use fontawesome in wordpress and for animated icon check this link [Fontawesome animated icons](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/animating-icons)

Comment: @varooneh thanks but where is still sheet ref and where is fa-bars?

Comment: If you want use animated fontawesome icon just need this code: ```<i class="fa fa-bar fa-spin"></i>```

Comment: @varooneh Thanks, that's great. Just that it top amd bottom bars to cross on click whilst middle bar disappears-not continuously revolving. Is there one for that? Thanks.